# socket.io session is undefined when refreshing page, but not when closing window

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a disconnect handler on the server side and if I close the window I can do `sock.user` to get the saved user. But if I refresh the browser instead of closing, the `sock.user` is undefined.

```
sock.on('chat:join', function(user){
    sock.user = user;
});

sock.on('disconnect', function(){
    var user = sock.user;

    //on window close, user is defined as expected
    //but on page refresh it is undefined.
});
```

In the `disconnect`, on window close, `user` is defined as expected, but on page refresh it is `undefined`.

Edit: I also tried using `sock.set` and `sock.get` and its still undefined when refreshing page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong arguments to the callback. First is `err`, second should be `user`.

I could not find this function for `get` and `set` in the codebase.